# Android simple Login authen. with MySQl and php

Tags: php, android, asynchronous, task

Hello everybody i'm trying to create a simple login activity that will authenticate user from MySql database using php .... I got errors that I couldn't solve ... please anybody help me

Here the Main Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://servername.com/mypath/Login.php";
EditText un , pas;
Button ok;
ProgressDialog prog;


JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Idintify();
    ok.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new ToLogin().execute();
        }
    });
}


public void Idintify(){
    un = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Un);
    pas = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Pas);
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);

}


class ToLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{


    boolean failure = false; 

    @Override protected void onPreExecute() { 
        super.onPreExecute(); 
        prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
        prog.setMessage("Login wait ..."); 
        prog.setIndeterminate(false); 
        prog.setCancelable(true); 
        prog.show(); 
        }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //int success;

        int sucess;
          String username = un.getText().toString();
          String password = pas.getText().toString();


                 try {

                         List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                          param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                          param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));


                          Log.d("request!", "starting");

                          JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL,"POST", param);

                          Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                          sucess = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                          if (sucess == 1) {

                              Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                              Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notifications.class);

                              finish();

                              startActivity(i);

                              return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                          }else{

                              Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));

                              return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);



                          }

                      } catch (JSONException e) {

                          e.printStackTrace();

                      }







                 return null;       

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String message) { 
        prog.dismiss(); 
        if (message != null){ 
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
        }




}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

and that is the JSONParser.java

```
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {
try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    try {

        if(method == "POST"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
           is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }else if(method == "GET"){
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
       }          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

    }

    return jObj;

}
```

and that's my PHP code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE0XA.jpg)

My Logcat errors

```
02-28 20:10:48.132: D/Login attempt(2476): {"message":"You have been sucessfully login","success":1}
02-28 20:10:48.132: D/Login Successful!(2476): {"message":"You have been sucessfully login","success":1}
02-28 20:10:48.852: I/Choreographer(2476): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-28 20:10:48.952: W/dalvikvm(2476): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-28 20:10:50.375: I/Choreographer(2476): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-28 20:10:51.852: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2476): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.tst/com.example.tst.Notifications}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at com.example.tst.MainActivity$ToLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:114)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at com.example.tst.MainActivity$ToLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-28 20:10:53.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     ... 4 more
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476): Activity com.example.tst.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d1d988 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-640,128} that was originally added here
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.tst.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d1d988 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-640,128} that was originally added here
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at com.example.tst.MainActivity$ToLogin.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:73)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at com.example.tst.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-28 20:10:54.352: E/WindowManager(2476):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your errors and logcat

Comment: @helldawg13 I post them

Answer (score 0):

The important line is here:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.tst/com.example.tst.Notifications}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

This error means that the Activity that you are trying to go after you login does not exist.

The problem is here:

```
if (sucess == 1) {
     Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notifications.class);
     MainActivity.this.finish();
     startActivity(i);
     return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
}
```

Check that your Target Activity is named Notifications and it is declared in your AndroidManifest.xml

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: what do you mean? did you check what i suggest?

Comment: I add this line on the manifest file
<activity android:name=".Notifictions" android:label= "@string/app_name"/>

Comment: did it work? Make sure you change it on the Intent too

Comment: I try this but same errors:

<activity
            android:name="com.example.tst.Notifications"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tst.Notifications" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

do not move activity in dobackground() Method Change your code put in onPostExecute() and not finish() first startActivity(i) after finsih() like following code

```
if (success == 1) 
    {
        Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notifications.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));  
    }
```